# How to deal with $\int\limits_{L}z\cos(2\pi z \bar{z})\,dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The original integral is:

$$\int\limits_{L}z\cos(2\pi z \bar{z})\,dz$$

where $$L = \{|z| = 1; \quad 0 \le \arg \le \pi \}$$

very well seen that integration region is the semi-circle $[0;\pi]$ but I am totally confused how to deal with cosine's arg :(

Comment: Hint: $z\bar z=|z|^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that because $z\bar z= |z|^2=1$, the integral becomes, $$\int \limits_{L} z \cos 2\pi \, dz = \int \limits_{L} z \, dz = \,?$$

Comment: and finally $$\int z\, dz$$ can be taken as $$\int_{0}^{\pi} z\, dz$$ ?

Comment: @M.Mass, Yes, so the answer is $\pi z$.

Comment: No. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_{L}z\cos(2\pi z \bar{z})\,dz= \int_0^{\pi}e^{it} \cos (2 \pi e^{it}e^{-it}) i e^{it} dt=i \int_0^{\pi}e^{2it} dt=0$.